# How to pass self to python decorator?

Tags: python, python-decorators, syntactic-sugar

There is sample code as below:

```py
class Cage(object):
    def __init__(self, func, parent):
        self.func = func
        self.parent = parent

    def __call__(self):
        print('Decorator Cage')
        print(self.parent.age)   # I need to use instance's object of Dog
        print(self.parent.name)
        self.func()

    class Dog(object):
        def __init__(self, age, name):
            self.age = age
            self.name = name

        def dosomedecorate(self):
            print('Do something')

        @Cage
        def dosugar(self):
            print('Do something')

if __name__ == "__main__":

    poppy = Dog(20, 'Louis')

    Cage(poppy.dosomething, poppy)() # It works, but looks weird...

    poppy.dosugar() # Use syntactic sugar will raise error
```

In this case,

I want to decorate function in `class Dog` with decorator `class Cage`.

But, `Cage` need to use object in `Dog`

I tried to use syntactic sugar as below:

```
        @Cage
        def dosugar(self):
            print('Do something')
```

, then raise error:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'parent'
```

Is it possible to pass `self` to decorator?

Or other way to deal with this kind of case?

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like that:

```py
def Cage(func):
    def wrapper(self, *args):
        print('Decorator Cage')
        print(self.age)
        print(self.name)
        return func(self, *args)
    
    return wrapper
```

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing further details, this at least works for your example while keeping the `Cage` class (though I prefer the answer by catalin).

```
class Cage(object):
    def __init__(self, func, parent):
        self.func = func
        self.parent = parent

    def __call__(self):
        print('Decorator Cage')
        print(self.parent.age)
        print(self.parent.name)
        self.func(self.parent)

def cage(func):
    def wrapper(self):
        return Cage(func, self)()
    return wrapper

class Dog(object):
    def __init__(self, age, name):
        self.age = age
        self.name = name

    @cage
    def dosugar(self):
        print('Do something')
```

Which prints out

```
Decorator Cage
20
Louis
Do something
```